# How do I insert a date to my datagridview in Date Modified Column?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am using a Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL Server 2005.
I'm trying to insert a current date in my data grid view in the Date_Modified Column when I click the Update_button.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the date in `datagridview` column. Then why `sql` tag?

Comment: any thing you have tried so far?

Comment: @Eminem: I hope `datagridview` is used in Winforms.

Comment: i have a date_modify column, i want to have a value being inserted in that column every time i click the update button..

what should i do? please help